# How can I resize an application window with a DDE command? [Windows OS/Filemaker]

Tags: filemaker, kiosk, point-of-sale, multiple-monitors, dde

I'm using Filemaker to create a Point of Sale solution.

It is being run on Windows OS with a dual monitor screen. A cashier facing 15" 1024x768 screen and a customer facing 8" 800x600 screen.

Filemaker **can send Dynamic Data Exchange commands via a script**. What I would like to know is **what parameters to pass** through **so that the** filemaker **application window will resize to 1824x768** so when a script moves the second window to Left:1024 top:0 it will be visible.

Three parameters are required: "Service Name", "Topic" and "Commands".

Answer (score 0):

DDE messages are separate Windows messages of their own. You can't send e.g. WM_RESIZE via DDE. Unless there is some documented DDE-based protocol that you know the target understands that will do it, what you ask isn't possible.

Comment: Is there anyway you can think of that might accomplish this, so I can then try and think of a way to link the solution to Filemaker. For example, I use a plugin (MonkeyBread Software) that extends Filemaker's functionality a great deal and with this plugin I can run Windows Scripts. Can what I need be done with a Windows Script?

Answer (score 0):

So you want to Maximise the FileMaker application across two monitors?

I don't think you can do that natively in Windows without an application such as [UltraMon](http://www.realtimesoft.com/ultramon/)